# Positioning Preference?

Tags: css

Of the 4 method listed below, which are more compatible and/or performance driven when animating? To keep the topic more isolated, lets say while animating a navigation pane (drawer) into view from left to right.

- `margin/`padding`/`border-left` ([further reading on negative margins](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/))
- `position:absolute`
- `position:relative`
- `transform:translateX` adjustment ([Support for Transforms](http://caniuse.com/#search=translate))

From what I know, position:relative, padding, margin, & borders generate reflows and repaints... is the impact really that big?

whereas positions:absolute/fixed generates reflows only.

I'm not entirely sure what translateY does, although it does pass transitions to the GPU which may not be desirable on mobile, from what I've *read* (not personally tested). Is this accurate? Is it just splitting hairs?

I'm looking for a well supported method of animating that performs well from mobile to desktop (IE9+) and is CSS based. I haven't tested a particular path but have used all at one point or another, just curious which is preferred and why?

I'll provide one example to demonstrate how they all can achieve the same effect...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/94yf1a39/

```
/* hardware acceleration */

.margin,
.relative,
.absolute,
.translate-x{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)}

/* margin */

.margin{
    margin-left:-200px;
    transition:margin-left 200ms, color 200ms cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.83,.67) 20ms}
    .margin:hover{margin-left:50px}

/* positioning */

.absolute{position:absolute}

.relative-wrap,
.relative{position:relative}

.relative-wrap{margin-bottom:2.4rem}

.relative,
.absolute{
    left:-200px;
    transition:left 200ms, color 200ms cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.83,.67) 20ms}

.relative:hover,
.absolute:hover{left:50px}

/* translate */

.translate-x{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200px);
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    transition:transform 200ms, color 200ms cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.83,.67) 20ms;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;}

.translate-x:hover{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
    transform: translateX(50px)}

/* will change */

.will-change .margin{will-change: margin-left}
.will-change .position{will-change: left}
.will-change .translate-x{will-change: transform}
.will-change .margin,
.will-change .position,
.will-change .translate-x{will-change: color}
```